# Strange Haskell/GHC output

Tags: haskell

Could anybody explain this output to me? Im completely new at Haskell and do not know why that happens.

```
import Data.Char

o=ord 'f'

main=do print (o==102)
    print (mod (102^2087) 9797)
    print (mod (o^2087) 9797)
```

Output:

```
xxx:~/Arbeitsfläche$ runhaskell st.hs
True
5253
0
```

GHC version 7.4.1, Ubuntu

Comment: `ord` has type `Char -> Int`, so `o` is an `Int`. In Haskell, `Int`s have an upper bound, but `Integer`s do not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `o` has type `Int` which has a limited range and thus `(mod (o^2087) 9797)` is also an `Int`. However, the constant `102` is of a generic numeric type (`Num a => a`) and `(mod (102^2087) 9797)` is of generic integral type (`Integral a => a`). When this generic integral type must be resolved to a concrete type, which happens when applying `print`, the default resolution is to choose `Integer`, an unbounded integral type. The details of this resolution are described in section [4.3.4 Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) of the [Haskell 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).

Comment: That seems to fix the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [`ord`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputchar/ord_f.html) is a function which returns the numerical representation of a character, in this case 102.

1. Your first line (`print (o==102)`) is checking whether `o` is equal to `102` which it is, hence the output `True`.
2. The second line (`print (mod (102^2087) 9797)`) applies two arguments to the [`mod`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/mod_f.html) function.  The `mod` function returns the remainder when the first argument is divided by the second argument.  This is [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) so no fractional parts are allowed.  The caret operator (`^`) means that the [exponent](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Exponentiation_operator#Haskell) is taken.  i.e. "102 to the power of 2087".
3. The final line (`print (mod (o^2087) 9797)`) does the same as the second line, with different arguments.

Hope that's clear!

Comment: I think Nymer is confused because the final line outputs 0 instead of 5253, even though `o == 102`.

Comment: Not really, but that wasn't me.